# Java Mobile Development

Tags: java, android, mobile

I currently make Java (eclipse) applications for PC use.  Everything from basic standalone programs, to client/server programs.  I got online and noticed that most of the development positions are for Android development in my area. How different is Android application development from regular JAVA development programs, and where would I find information to get myself started?

- I do not know JScript, HTML, or any other web development tools, and all the descriptions just say "Mobile Java developer, Android market".

Comment: Thanks everyone, they were all great options (and led me pretty much to the same place).  It sounds like since I know SWING GUI development, with AWT action listeners, that this should be fairly similar. I will look into this more when I get home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most Android application are written in Java, using Android SDK provided on [Android's Developper Website](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). The best place to start next woud be the [Training Guides](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html).

To answer your question, if you've worked with Java before, done a little bit of work with UI (Swing, AWT, ...), you should be real fine, the most challenging, yet important thing would be to understand the [Activity/Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) and [Intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) concepts. Once you know these, you'll be fine.

Take a good look at the Hello Worlds, try to read as many tutorial (god knows how much there are out there).

Answer (score 3):

I would start here:

http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

I have never developed an application for PC use, but when I search for example code for my Android apps I search more or less only for pure Java examples. In that way its the same. What you might want to read about is the Android Lifecycle and about how to make the graphical part of an Android app by using the standard Android UI elements. If you already know Java I think you'll get the hang of it quickly!

Answer (score 3):

Android applications can be developed using various platforms and SDK 
These are few that I remember

1. Native using C/C++
2. Java
3. Then using Adobe
4. Then there is phoneGap
5. You can also use .Net (using MonoDroid if I remember)

However Google has its sdk basd on Java and a very well documented site [here](http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html).Android is not much different then regular java development since its uses Java Api.But you need to understand how android system works.

Besides you can always search SO and Google if you have any problem.

Most importantly your choices must be on your interest then Market Trend.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know TotalCross (www.totalcross.com)? It is a JAVA cross development platform for mobile apps. There are some pros and cons like any other cross-platform, but you will be able to distribute to iOS, Android and Windows too.